# Объединение блоков строк

Tags: c#

Есть список списков строк.

```
List<string> firstList = new List<string>(){"one","two,"three"};
List<string> secondList = new List<string>(){"three","four,"five"};
List<string> thirdList = new List<string>(){"ten","eleven,"twelve"};

List<List<string>> blocksOfStrings = new List<List<string>>(){firstList,secondList,thirdList};
```

И нужно написать метод, который объединит листы с пересекающимися значениями. Т.е. в данном случае у нас
firstList и secondList содержат одинаковый string - "three", значит их нужно объединить в один List с удалением дубликатов

Написал для этого метод,

```
List<List<string>> MergeBlockOfStrings(List<List<string>> blocksOfStrings)
{
    List<List<string>> newBlockOfStrings = new List<List<string>>();

    foreach (var block in blocksOfStrings)
    {
        foreach (var block2 in blocksOfStrings)
        {
            if (block2 != block)
            {
                foreach (var str1 in block)
                {
                    foreach (var str2 in block2)
                    {
                        if (str1 == str2)
                        {
                            var newBlock = new List<string>();
                            foreach (var firstBlockString in block)
                            {
                                if (!newBlock.Contains(firstBlockString))
                                {
                                    newBlock.Add(firstBlockString);
                                }
                            }
                            foreach (var secondBlockString in block2)
                            {
                                if (!newBlock.Contains(secondBlockString))
                                {
                                    newBlock.Add(secondBlockString);
                                }
                            }
                            newBlockOfStrings.Add(newBlock);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return newBlockOfStrings;
}
```

но он громоздкий и выглядит ужасно. Можно как-то это сделать проще и понятнее, например через LINQ?

Как должно работать

На входе в метод

```
List<string> firstList = new List<string>(){"one","two","three"};
List<string> secondList = new List<string>(){"three","four","five"};
List<string> thirdList = new List<string>(){"ten","eleven","twelve"};
```

Использование метода

```
List<List<string>> MergedBlocksOfStrings = MergeBlockOfStrings(blockOfStrings);
```

На выходе должны быть

```
List<string> mergedList = new List<string>(){"one","two","three","four","five"};
List<string> thirdList = new List<string>(){"ten","eleven","twelve"};

List<List<string>> blocksOfStrings = new List<List<string>>(){mergedList,thirdList};
```

Comment: `blocksOfStrings.SelectMany(x => x).Distinct();`

Comment: @EvgeniyZ если это рабочий вариант, оформите пожалуйста его как ответ

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Это же просто защита от дубликатов, но там нет объединения листов строк

Comment: Уточните. Списков всегда три или произвольное количество? Что, если одинаковое значение ("three") будет более чем в двух списках? Их все объединить в один?

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov списков может быть сколько угодно -  задача объединить списки с общими элементами, а у которых нет общих - не трогать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Буду рад, если кто-то напишет в комментарии об эффективности этого алгоритма и его подводных камнях.

**Идея**

1. Берем самый левый блок `left`
2. Проверяем поочередно с правой частью списка блоков, есть ли там блок `right`, элементы которого присутствуют в списке `left`. Если есть - см. шаг 3, если нет, см. шаг 7
3. Объединяем списки в один `join`
4. Удаляем `left` и `right` из исходного списка блоков
5. Вставляем на место `left` новый блок `join`
6. Завершаем цикл по правой части списка
7. Если блок `left` - не последний в списке, то переходим ко следующему по списку блоку `left` и повторяем шаг 2. Иначе - завершение алгоритма

По итогу в исходном списке будет находиться ожидаемый результат.

**Код:**

```
private static async Task Main(string[] args)
{
    List<string> firstList = new List<string>() { "one", "two", "three" };
    List<string> secondList = new List<string>() { "three", "four", "five" };
    List<string> thirdList = new List<string>() { "ten", "eleven", "twelve" };

    List<List<string>> blocksOfStrings = new List<List<string>>() { firstList, secondList, thirdList};

    var result = Intersect(blocksOfStrings);
}

private static List<List<string>> Intersect(List<List<string>> blocksOfStrings)
{
    for (var i = 0; i < blocksOfStrings.Count; i++)
    {
        var left = blocksOfStrings[i];

        for (var j = i + 1; j < blocksOfStrings.Count; j++)
        {
            var right = blocksOfStrings[j];

            if (AreIntersect(left, right))
            {
                var join = left.Union(right).ToList();
                blocksOfStrings.Remove(left);
                blocksOfStrings.Remove(right);
                blocksOfStrings.Insert(i, join);
                i--;
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    return blocksOfStrings;
}

private static bool AreIntersect(List<string> first, List<string> second)
{
    return first.Intersect(second).Any();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Для объединения можно использовать Concat, для дублей Union,

```
List<string> firstList = new List<string>() { "one", "two", "three"};
List<string> secondList = new List<string>() { "three", "four", "five"};
List<string> thirdList = new List<string>() { "ten", "eleven", "twelve"};

List<string> result = firstList.Union(secondList).Union(thirdList).ToList();
```

Если List содержит класс то можно еще объеденять через общий интерфейс, например:

```
firstList.Cast<ICommon>().Concat(secondList.Cast<ICommon>()).Concat(thirdList.Cast<ICommon>());
```